# kotlin data class HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: json, spring, kotlin

I'm trying this code with postman, but nothing works, why ?

What i send :

```
{
    "name":"front_msel",
    "gitlabId": "83",
    "fichierVersion":"VERSION"
}
```

My spring controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
class ProjectController(val projectRepository: ProjectRepository) {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectController::class.java)

    @PostMapping()
    fun saveProject(@RequestBody payload: Project): String {
        log.info("project: '{}'", payload.toString())
       return projectRepository.save(payload).gitlabId?:"-1"
    }

}
```

What i get :

```
{
"timestamp": 1505917417221,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.......model.Project: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.......model.Project: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@66ba61d9; line: 2, column: 2]",
"path": "/projects"
```

}

My project data class :

```
data class Project(val name:String?, val gitlabId: String?, val fichierVersion: String?)
```

I doubled check params, it's not a wording mistake, what does this things doesn't works ?

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Todd, the problem was resolve by adding null value to my param, to generate a zero argument constructor. Thanks !

```
data class Project(val name:String? = null, val gitlabId: String? = null, val fichierVersion: String? = null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by making two slight changes.

First, since all your `Project` fields are nullable, provide default values so the compiler will generate a zero argument constructor:

```
data class Project(val name:String? = null, val gitlabId: String? = null, val fichierVersion: String? = null)
```

Second, it seems that Spring wants your fields to be in `snakey_case` rather than `camelCase`, so change your payload to this:

```
{
  "name":"front_msel",
  "gitlab_id": "83",
  "fichier_version":"VERSION"
}
```

Comment: Your first point was good and make it works ! But didn't need to change my fields in snakey_case :) Thanks to solve it